# Radio input not working with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Radio input not working with localStorage

I used localStorage for many examples and work with me good except starRating.

Here is example [example](http://www.claim-coin.com/)

I tried many codes , but does not work

Please give me example. Sorry I'm newbie.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th STYLE="width:200px">link</th>
         <th STYLE="width:200px">rating</th>
         <th STYLE="width:200px">Options</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">site a</A>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span class="starRating">
            <input CLASS="inputrating" CHECKED id="rating_9_5" type="radio" name="rating_9" value="5">
            <label for="rating_9_5">5</label>
            <input CLASS="inputrating" id="rating_9_4" type="radio" name="rating_9" value="4">
            <label for="rating_9_4">4</label>
            <input CLASS="inputrating" id="rating_9_3" type="radio" name="rating_9" value="3">
            <label for="rating_9_3">3</label>
            <input CLASS="inputrating" id="rating_9_2" type="radio" name="rating_9" value="2">
            <label for="rating_9_2">2</label>
            <input CLASS="inputrating" id="rating_9_1" type="radio" name="rating_9" value="1">
            <label for="rating_9_1">1</label></span>
      </td>
      <td>
         add
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">site b</A>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span class="starRating">
```

5
4
3
2
1
          
          
             add

```js
$(".starRating").on("click", function(){
        selected_rating = $('input', this).data("inputrating");
        selected_id = $('input', this).data("rating-id"); 
        console.log(selected_rating)

    });
```

Comment: There is nothing in this code that does anything with local storage. What data do you want to store?

Comment: i have many links i need usa starRating for all link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your event binding to the Radio Buttons, not the spans that contain them.

Next, you need to access the values of the radio buttons, rather than using the jQuery .data() method, which I'm not sure what you are doing with.

```
 this.value
```

In the event handler is all you need for that.

**Next, you need to actually store the values, which you didn't have any code for:**

```
if(window.localStorage){
  localStorage.setItem("Site A Rating", this.value);
} else {
  console.log("localStorage not supported."); 
}
```

Here is a working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6jfey3cj/4/

And a screen shot showing the different site's ratings in localStorage.

[image]

Comment: i need usa Local Storage not need alert  Local Storage work in my site with timer http://www.claim-coin.com/

Comment: You didn't post your localStorage code. But, first, let's make sure we have the right data. Can you answer what $(this).data("rating-id"); is supposed to return? After we get that straight, we can add the local storage part.

Comment: My answer shows how to receive the values of radio button groups and store them in local storage, like your question asked. I provided a fully functional example, with a screen shot confirming the result. All it would take to make this work for more sites is to extend the example that I have already given you. You have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue you are struggling with is how to decide which element is best to trigger your function on. You are currently triggering on `.starRating` which is a span. It is possible to use that as the trigger but makes much more sense to simply fire the function whenever someone chooses a value on `.inputrating` which is a class that is unique to all your star rating radio buttons.

Try this code out:

```
$(".inputrating").on("change", function(){

    checked_rating = $(this).val();
    checked_id = $(this).attr('id');

    console.log(checked_rating);
    console.log(checked_id);

});
```

If you notice I changed `click` to `change`. This will make it so that your code only fires once on rating select. That way if you end up running an ajax function to update a database it won't keep getting called over and over if the user decides to spam click the same radio button over and over.

Here is a working fiddle demonstrating the solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u9k8dus/3/)

Comment: @sabrys56 What errors are you getting? Did you load up the link I posted at the bottom? That is a working version of what you posted in your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for pointing this out. I was not aware of this. I will change it back to `click` for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Just so I'm clear do you mean `change` will fire when clicking another radio button with the same `name` attr? I tried this out just now and change only fired when it was selected. Am I missing something?

Comment: I click 2 satr but i refreshed site back to 5 satr

Comment: @sabrys56 Does the correct data get output in your console? Your question has nothing to do with storing a variable anywhere to reload on page refresh.

Comment: @Keeleon Sorry, I had a brain cramp! i was getting my .NET `CheckChanged` event confused with my JavaScript `change`!

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ahh! That makes sense, no worries. Thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: Local Storage work in my site with timer claim-coin.com

Answer (score -1):

You can change your javascript function as below

```
$(".inputrating").on("click", function(){
    selected_rating = $(this).val();
    selected_id = this.id;
    console.log(selected_rating);
    console.log(selected_id);
```

});

updated fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/tfhg15xw/2/

Comment: `selected_id` will be null in your code and your code does nothing with local storage.

Comment: makes sense, I updated the fiddle but anyways the question was not clear with local storage thing. Anyways your answer does take care of the storage. But do you think sessionstorage be used instead of localstorage ?

Comment: Not sure, but OP asked about local storage.